# How to convert a string to an inputstream in Bioclipse javascript editor?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to save an a string to a file in with a javascript in the [Bioclipse](http://bioclipse.net) workbench, by using

`ui.save( "filename", "my string" );`

...but get an error that ui.save takes only an inputstream as the second parameter.
How can I convert a string to an inputstream in the Bioclipse javascript context?

(Btw, I think Bioclipse uses the [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) Javascript implementation)

Comment: There is no built-in stream concept in javascript. Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: +1 for taking a bad question and making it a good one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this situation we have to fall back to Java.

You are trying to call the method ui.save which according to `man ui.save` looks like this:

```
> man ui.save
---------------------------------------------
ui.save(String filePath, InputStream content)
---------------------------------------------
Save the content of the InputStream to the given path.
```

So this method wants an InputStream. Rhino allows us to instantiate Java objects. This can probably be made much nicer...

```
var stream = new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(
                      new java.lang.String("Example String").getBytes("UTF-8") );
```

And then we call the method with this stream, (and an existing path where to save the file)

```
ui.save("/test/test.txt", stream);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a page describing java interop using Rhino: http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/ScriptingJava.html